# c++ threadsafe static constructor

Tags: c++, thread-safety

Given:

```
void getBlah() {
  static Blah* blah = new Blah();
  return blah;
}
```

In a multi threaded setting, is it possible that new Blah() is called more than once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard makes no guarantee about the thread safety of static initializations - you should treat the static initialization as requiring explicit synchronisation.

The quote Alexander Gessler gives:

> If control enters the declaration
>   concurrently while the object is being
>   initialized, the concurrent execution
>   shall wait for completion of the
>   initialization

is from the C++0x draft, and doesn't reflect the current C++ standard or the behaviour of many C++ compilers.

In the current C++ standard, that passage reads:

> If control re-enters the declaration (recursively) while the object is being
>   initialized, the behaviour is **undefined**

Comment: Even the C++0x draft has an example highlighting this very point at the end of para 4 of 6.7.

Answer (score 2):

No. But note that the pointer to `Blah` is `static`.

> **6.7 Declaration statement**
>
> 4 [...] Otherwise such an object is
> initialized the first time control
> passes through its declaration; such
> an object is considered initialized
> upon the completion of its
> initialization. If the initialization
> exits by throwing an exception, the
> initialization is not complete, so it
> will be tried again the next time
> control enters the declaration

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This pertains to the C++0x draft.

Quoting the standard (6.7-4):

> If control enters the declaration concurrently
>   while the object is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization

To my understanding, static initialization like this is thread-safe.

Comment: That's a quote from the C++0x draft.

Comment: Yes, indeed it's from the cpp0x draft. So I assume this line is missing in the current standard?

Comment: I've added the text from the current standard to my answer.

Comment: Why is this response down voted? I find it perfectly useful, even if it's citing a future draft.